# getQuote function in quantmod package

Tags: programming, quantmod

just wondering if there is a similar function that I can use to get the last traded price of a stock? Cuz the getQuote function from quantmod package does not seem to be working no more. It would show a message "Error in open.connection(con,"rb"): HTTP error 401."
All suggestions are much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked one of the authors of the R package. The function is known to be broken due to changes in the Yahoo API. The changes in this [PR](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/pull/383) ought to fix your issue.

Make sure you have the `remotes` package and install with `remotes::install_github("ethanbsmith/quantmod@382_add_session_getQuote")`